# Use sub-second precision on "earliest" in Splunk query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, time-precision

I have a Splunk search string. If I add **earliest=10/05/2020:23:59:58**, the search string still works. However, if I changed that to earliest=10/05/2020:23:59:58:**01**, I got an error message say **invalid value "10/05/2020:23:59:58:01" for time term 'earliest'**. Does that mean Splunk's **earliest** parameter's precision is to second only? I cannot find the answer in their documents.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I thought `..:23:59:58.010` worked (it does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`earliest`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/SearchTimeModifiers#List_of_time_modifiers)'s precision is limited to "standard" [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [epoch time](https://docs.splunk.com/Special:SplunkSearch/docs?product=Splunk&version=8.1.0&q=epoch+time) (ie the number of elapsed seconds since the dawn of Unix (arbitrarily set to 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 (or, sometimes, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59))) because the [`_time`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions) field holds whole-number *seconds*.

Splunk knows how to [convert](https://epochconverter.com) [timestamps](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/strftime) seen with *more* precision than mere seconds, but that does not mean `_time` natively holds them.

`_time`, and, therefore, anything that references it (like `earliest`) does not understand subsecond precision. For *that*, you will need to have another field that contains it in your event.

Answer (score 0):

For millisecond search time, include timeformat=%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%3N together with your earliest=10/05/2020:23:59:58:01.